# How do I output a sum of multiple cells on another sheet, only if the total is greater than 0?

Tags: google-sheets

As the title stated, currently I have the following:

`=SUM(Income!M4, Income!N4, Income!O4)`

How do I change that to only output the summed total if it is >0?

Essentially, like a `SUMIFS(Income!M4 + Income!N4 + Income!O4, ">0")`, but one that actually works?

Comment: do you want to sumif the sum is greater than 0 or if the cell is greater than 0?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(Income!M4, Income!N4, Income!O4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
=IF(SUM(Income!M4, Income!N4, Income!O4) > 0, SUM(Income!M4, Income!N4, Income!O4), "")
```